# Ng-Bootstrap open model of child component

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have a footer component that contains some terms and conditions ng-bootstrap modal. I use the footer component in other pages as well. Is there a way I can open the modal from my parent(lets say home component)? Here is something I tried:

home.component.html:

```
<a (click)="open(terms)">terms &amp; conditions</a>
```

home.component.ts:

```
open(content) {
  this.modalService.open(content).result.then((result) => {
  }, (reason) => {
  });
}
```

footer.component.html:

```
<ng-template #terms let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Terms &amp; Conditions</h4>
    <button (click)="d('Cross click')" type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    Test
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    Test
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

I tried this but nothing opens nor do I get an error. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can combine the footer component to the app component and reuse it across

Comment: can you explain a little further? new to angular and ng bootstrap. what your saying is merge the footer component into my app component and then use the same sort of opening function?

Comment: You have an example on the docs. Scroll to "Component as content": https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

Comment: @AJT_82 isn't that a component as content? But in my case, I have 2 separate components and one has the actual modal (along with other stuff that is not needed) and the second makes a call (need to open only the modal and not using the whole of first component). How is that possible?

Comment: Oh okay, I perhaps misunderstood your question a bit :)

Comment: @AJT_82 no issues. Any idea how to achieve this? Or do I need to maintain 2 modals - one for each component?

Comment: Why not make the modal as a separate component, which you can then open from any component. Do it like the sample link I gave. I think that would be the smartest thing to do?

Comment: again that would be another component(child) right. my problem is not with using it as a content but rather in making the call and activating it.

Comment: It doesn't need to be child, you can access it from anywhere in the module.